# instead of generating .xls file i am getting .php file on server side

Tags: php, excel, localhost, cpanel, server-side

I'm using following headers to generate excel file from database MySQL using PHP

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd-ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: attachments;filename=xxx.xls");
```

in localhost the output is xxx.xls which is correct file but in the server side i am getting xxx.php file (i am using a cpanel account for ftp)
guys please help me with a solution

Comment: setting a header does not magically create a valid xls file

Answer (score 1):

simply use

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xls"');
```

Comment: the headers doesn't matter whether i use  header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); or i use header('Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel'); the output is same

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use the following php code. 
You have to give an array with key value pair

```
      $data = array("Name"=> "foo", "age" => 25);
      $filename = "My File Name" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

     header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
     header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

     $flag = false;
     foreach($data as $row) {
        if(!$flag) {
            // display field/column names as first row
            echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
            $flag = true;
        }

        foreach ($row as $value){

            echo $value;
            echo "\t";
        }
        echo "\n";
     }
     exit;
```

Comment: Ok i understand, but my doubt is why i am getting two different outputs in different situations ?? at localhost the output is correct .xls file with required datas  but at server side the output is .php file with required datas